# Scala require() equivalent in Kotlin

Tags: scala, class, require, kotlin

In Scala we have a require method that is used to set preconditions to classes like this

```
class Rational(x: Int, y: Int) {
   require(y != 0, "denominator must be different than zero ")
```

My question is: Do we have something like that in Kotlin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kotlin stdlib also has a [`require`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html) method:

```
class Rational(x: Int, y: Int) {
    init {
        require(y != 0) { "denominator must be different than zero " }
    }
}
```

It also has a [`requireNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require-not-null.html), [`check`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/check.html), [`checkNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/check-not-null.html), [`assert`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/assert.html).

There are also various other assert methods in [kotlin-test](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/f91c01919b7ce1a4a69cedcbc757eb31e4c5c413/libraries/kotlin.test/shared/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/test).

Answer (score 2):

How about [Preconditions.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Preconditions.kt) or [Assert](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/assert.html) ?